# Changing the saved location of the program code by changing the code segment

Tags: x86, nasm, memory-segmentation

I know that the program code is stored in the code segment
On the other hand, to ensure that the BIOS does not load the bootloader at the desired address(the 0:0x7c00 or 0x7c0:0 problem), we must explicitly declare the segment code in the program(by using FAR JMP).
My question is, will our program be loaded again in the segment announced by us or, for example, the code is pre-processed and the address of the segment code defined by us replaces the BIOS default if needed?
What about GDT? Will it also be updated?

Comment: *to ensure that the BIOS does not load the bootloader at the desired address(the 0:0x7c00 or 0x7c00:0 problem), we must explicitly declare the segment code in the program(by using FAR JMP)* - What?  The BIOS *does* always load the bootloader at linear address `0x7C00`.  You only need to care about setting CS if you want to do any *absolute* accesses relative to the CS base, like near indirect jumps, or using `[cs: bx]` addressing modes instead of just setting DS and ES for data access.

Comment: The ORG directive tells NASM what to assume when filling in absolute addresses, it can't change where the BIOS loads your initial MBR or what it sets segment registers to.  `nasm -f bin bootsect.asm` just makes a flat 512-byte binary with no metadata (except the 2-byte signature at the end) which the BIOS loads.  You have to put instructions into your code to do stuff at run-time beyond that.

Comment: @Peter Cordes With jump we go to another code segment  (but our code is loaded in the default BIOS segment 0x7c0 or 0)
As far as I know, org has nothing to do with segment addresses, it only deals with labels

Comment: `0000:7C00` and `07C0:0000` are two logical addresses for the *same* linear address.  That's why you have to use the right `org` for the segment base you set, if you want absolute addressing modes like `mov ax, [foo]` to work.  If you set DS=0, you need `org  0x7c00`.  But if you set `DS=0x07c0`, you need `org 0`.  Yes, org deals with *offsets* (within a segment) NASM takes as the addresses for labels.  It's exactly the same for code as for data, except that direct near jumps use relative addressing (`jmp rel8` or `rel16`) so they're position-independent.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I understand now